# What does the PerformanceGoal option of FindMinimum do?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, options, undocumented

[`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) and [`FindMinimum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) both have a [`PerformanceGoal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html) option. It is not documented. What does it do?

This option is present in `Options[FindMinimum]` in Mathematica 12.0 and 12.1.

Comment: In both cases I get an error: "Unknown option PerformanceGoal..." with Mathematica 11.2. Which version do you use?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum It's present in 12.0+.

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe that could be clarified in the question to avoid confusion :-)

Comment: In 12.1 only, the format of the output is different. `FindMinimum[Cos[x], {x, 3}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]` gives `{-1., {3.14159}}` and not `{-1., {x -> 3.14159}}`.

Comment: I think I need to update...

Comment: That the structure of the result changes strikes me as a bug. This is more serious than lack of documentation for an input that is accepted as an option. This would break any code that expects the second part to be a list of rules.

Comment: The incorrect form of the result is most certainly a bug. In terms of what the option does, it affects some of the convex optimization methods. As usual for PerformanceGoal, it influences the automatic selection of method and choice of tolerance for a tradeoff between accuracy and speed.